# Distinguish Web Template and Web Theme

Tags: website-design, terminology, templates, themes

I am building my own CMS, and it's time to work with front-end stuff. I do research and am confused why `Wordpress` uses a folder named `theme` while `Joomla` uses `template` instead. (Can anyone explain this?)

What is the difference between a web Template and a web Theme?

How do you, as a web designer, distinguish them?

Comment: As an aside, I always wonder why CONTENT management systems insist on trying to be DESIGN management systems. ;)

Comment: To add to the confusion, Wordpress has 'Page Templates' which  basically let you apply a different theme to a specific page.  Interesting that they used the term 'template' instead of 'Page Theme.'

Answer (score 3):

**Template** - Something that serves as a model for others to copy: "a template for change".

**Theme** - Give a particular setting or ambience to (a venue or activity): "themed menus".

So in essence, looking at the definition, a template usually refers to a frame. A set of building blocks grouped in a given way which lets you fill it with your own content. A template usually infers more than merely the aesthetic feel, different templates usually involves different layout, different means of navigation etc.

A theme however usually revolves around the same frame ("template"), and merely sets the aesthetic shell of the website. A theme usually sets the colouring, fonts, style etc. Another term you usually see used for theme is "Color scheme".

Answer (score 2):

In this context, a **template** defines the **structure** of the output, while a **theme** defines the **look**.

In reality, these two concerns are not always clearly separated. In the Joomla! world, many professional templates are themable, since one can change the styling with configuration options. So themes are often part of a template, and a template can be themable.